# joomla 2.5 - probleme d'ACL

Tags: joomla2.5, acl

I'm struggling to set up backoffice acls for my users on a joomla 2.5 website.
1) First, is it possible to give read permission to every articles for a group and write/delete/update permissions only to those created by the user?
I managed to handle the second part but it looks like it is not possible to give the read permission to all the articles to all users without the modify permission. Is that true?
2) For some reason, I couldn't let my non-superadministrators users access to the editor features (all the buttons above the editors to change text color, underline, etc.). They can edit the articles but it looks like there is a specific permission to toggle the editor. Am I correct? How can I fix this?

Thanks very much for your help. I appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Save yourself a ton of effort and buy ACL Manager. You should be able to grant read access to all users with edit own/create permissions for other users. It's just a pain to find the settings in Joomla. ACL manager puts everything in one place and it's easy to understand.

Next, JCE Editor has the ability to have multiple editor profiles that can be configured per extension/user group. You should be able to set the editor up exactly how you want based on the user group the user belongs to.